# What action attribute should I set to an HTML form if the POST route uses RegEx?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

So I'm trying to make a post route with RegEx, but I don't know what should I set to action in the HTML form so they match.

I tried to set it like the POST route, even though I knew it wouldn't work... I had to try.

```js
router.get('/judet/:id([0-9]{2})', middleware.access2, function(req, res)
{
      var title = "Dashboard";
      res.render("dashboard", {title: title});
});
router.post('/judet/:id([0-9]{2})/new', middleware.access2, function(req, res)
{
      X.create({
        fname: req.body.fname,
        lname: req.body.lname,
      }, function(err) {
          if(err)
          {
              return console.log(err);
          }
          else
          {
              res.redirect("back");
          }
      });
}); ///post route
```

```html
<form action="/judet/:id([0-9]{2})/new" method="POST">
    //form content
</form>
```

What should I set to the action attribute so it matches the post route? Thanks.

///edit: If I pass the id in the get route like this `res.render("dashboard", {title: title, id:req.params.id});`, how can I use that in the ejs? I was thinking about this `<form action="/judet/<%= id  %>/new" method="POST">` but I will get this: `Unexpected token = while compiling EJS`.
///edit 2: it's working now. I set `<form action="/judet/<% = id  %>/new" method="POST">` and the syntax was wrong because equal has to be right after the %.

Comment: You would either need an actual `id` value rendered in the html or create the `action` url client side based on some known `id` value there

Comment: @charlietfl: Yeah. I thought about it too. Check my edit.

Comment: *"it won't work"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement

Comment: Syntax error. check my second edit. Thanks for the idea. Post your idea as an answer and I will accept it asap.

Comment: Are you using ejs templating engine? You should have mentioned that

Answer (score 1):

`"/judet/:id([0-9]{2})/new"` problem with this is, the action should contain exact id.It cannot be an expression. If you're sending the id, it means you have the id.Let's say the id is 123456. Then the form should have:
`"/judet/123456/new"`. Just because the route handler is using regex doesn't mean the html form should too